# labelling vertical lines with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I have a dataset that looks something like this,

```
df<-structure(list(Year = c(1985L, 1986L, 1987L, 1988L, 1989L, 1990L, 
                        1991L, 1992L, 1993L, 1994L, 1995L, 1996L, 1997L, 1998L, 1999L,2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 1985L, 1986L, 1987L, 1988L, 1989L, 1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 1993L, 1994L, 1995L, 1996L, 1997L, 1998L,  1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L,                         2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 1985L, 1986L, 1987L, 1988L,  1989L, 1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 1993L, 1994L, 1995L, 1996L, 1997L, 1998L, 1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 1985L, 1986L, 1987L, 1988L, 1989L, 1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 1993L, 1994L, 1995L, 1996L, 1997L, 1998L, 1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L,  2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L),
               varclass = structure(c(5L,5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L,5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L,  7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L),
                                    .Label = c("r_mean_dp_C_EU_PTA", "r_mean_dp_C_eu_esr_sum", "r_mean_TS_dp_C_EU_PTA", "r_mean_TS_dp_C_eu_esr_sum", "r_mean_dp_C_US_PTA", "r_mean_dp_C_us_esr_sum", "r_mean_TS_dp_C_US_PTA", "r_mean_TS_dp_C_us_esr_sum"), class = "factor"), 
               score = c(0, 0.0243131684738152, 0.0295348762350131, 1.24572619158458, 1.20624633452509, 1.57418568231032, 1.45479246796848, 2.38700784566208, 2.62865525326503,  2.26401361870534, 2.67319203680329, 2.64440548764366, 3.10459526464658, 3.05231530072328, 3.32660416229216, 4.14909239351474, 3.76404440984403, 
                3.79766644256544, 4.55279786294561, 5.57506946922008, 6.83412605593388,   8.07241989452914, 9.10370786838265, 9.51564633960853, 8.64357423479438, 9.10723202296861, 10, 9.06442082870898, 0, 0.00309681975626394,  0.00376191973176611, 0.31456863316694, 0.307467479949235, 0.393381408917437,  0.369438522116308, 2.72595849026258, 3.02912715393088, 2.68234740512793,  3.04191351961057, 3.00285602012791, 3.53353155000059, 3.56064849955087, 
                3.8582842780802, 4.41758875010321, 3.86352795800086, 3.87742698588076, 4.75555995695473, 5.25498063194254, 6.83035779491644, 7.94400595857329, 8.90724897806749, 9.63957864779812, 8.45971275397907, 8.90268516213906,   10, 8.67387866657026, 0, 0.0971144336795407, 0.095032354957329,  0.324563912754777, 0.309037243530711, 0.445594208900048, 0.408585357361577,  0.984622633943152, 0.885285042777509, 0.854437578777773, 0.899346941764503,   0.713835758098677, 0.923205921767153, 0.885795460138979, 0.907706909901698,   1.26691097637723, 1.38531675474906, 1.46801357426345, 2.40528143410555,   6.11127334356639, 6.87984183345601, 8.58685934192075, 9.81477059919623,  10, 8.91400803949761, 9.13396140936897, 8.91190146236915, 9.31841494169555, 
                 0, 0.0131639497352947, 0.012881722072468, 0.0747427246588618,  0.074583753038409, 0.101240906800678, 0.0942176097616221, 1.01715224261827,  0.955422044148621, 0.930088131161646, 0.983316358580305, 0.814500687241286, 1.04433781820825, 1.00311623335088, 1.03043794235494, 1.25737311039187, 1.24242809142003, 1.30488643766672, 2.07282625012893, 5.9283639095883,   6.84735189008267, 8.44992964327563, 9.67266470058815, 10, 8.83518011553472, 
 9.08678510978114, 8.89558771137843, 9.22647697054944)), row.names = c(NA,-112L), 
class = "data.frame")
```

I and I am creating the following plot:

```
plot<- df %>%  
      ggplot(aes(x= Year, y= score, color = varclass)) +
           geom_line() + 
           geom_vline(xintercept = c(1992, 2004), linetype="dotted", size = 0.3)
```

The issue is that I am not able to label the vertical lines as I would like. In particular, I would like to label the 1992 line as "NAFTA". While 2004 line as "PAFTA". These are important events that affect my series. Ideally, the labels should appear on the right below the "varclass" labels.

I have tried doing the following

```
events<-structure(list(year = c(1992L, 2004L), 
                  event = structure(1:2, .Names = c("a","b"), 
                  .Label = c("NAFTA", "PAFTA"), 
                  class = "factor")), 
                  row.names = c("a", "b"), 
                  class = "data.frame")

plot<- df %>%  
       ggplot(aes(x= Year, y= score, color = varclass)) +
          geom_line() + 
          geom_vline(aes(xintercept=year, color=events),data=tst)
```

However, the legend becomes confusing with crosses.

Any idea on how to have a clean graph, with black vertical event lines and a clear labelling?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe this will help, you can add `geom_text` to your first plot

```
plot + 
geom_text(aes(x=2004, label="\nPAFTA", y=9), colour="red", angle=90) +
geom_text(aes(x=1992, label="\nNAFTA", y=9), colour="red", angle=90)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't answer your question directly, but I thought as an alternative you could have the labels as annotations on the graph:

```
df%>%  ggplot(aes(x= Year, y= score, color = varclass)) +geom_line() + 
  geom_vline(xintercept = 1992, linetype="dotted", size = 0.3) +   geom_vline(xintercept = 2004, linetype="dotted", size = 0.3) +
  annotate("text", x = 1994, y = 10.5, label = "NAFTA") +
  annotate("text", x = 2006, y = 10.5, label = "PAFTA")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `geom_text` with a new `data` argument setting. But you must also set `inherit.aes = FALSE`, so that the former `data = df` is not used by the geom.

Also, I have changed the name of the plot, from `plot` (the name of a base R function) to `g`.

```
g <- ggplot(df, aes(x= Year, y= score, color = varclass)) +
  geom_line() + 
  geom_vline(xintercept = c(1992, 2004), linetype="dotted", size = 0.3) 

g + geom_text(data = events, 
              mapping = aes(x = year, y = c(10.5, 10.5), label = event),
              inherit.aes = FALSE,
              hjust = 1)
```

[image]